# Can I get dialog from Activity.?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have a function activity as a parameter. I'm trying return a dialog shown on this activity,can I do this or not.?

```
private Dialog getDialogFromActivity(Activity activity){
     Dialog dialog = null;
     //code get dialog from activity here
     return dialog;
}
```

Comment: Yes you can do it. If activity is not `null`

Comment: yes, the activity is not null, how can I do.?

Comment: @NguyenThanhAn i shared one example below.

Comment: Could you please share your function, then only we can identify is it posible

Comment: private Dialog getDialogFromActivity(Activity activity){
    Dialog dialog = null ;
    // get dialog from activity
    return dialog;
}

Can I do that.?

Answer (score 0):

or you can make a dialog class and you can call it from everywhere:

```
public class AlertDialogManager {
    /**
     * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
     * @param context - application context
     * @param title - alert dialog title
     * @param message - alert message
     * @param status - success/failure/info (used to set icon)
     *               - pass null if you don't want icon
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
            String icon) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(icon == "fail"){
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.fail);
        }else if(icon == "true"){
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.success);
        }else if(icon == "info"){
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.info);
        }

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dialog is in DialogFragment, you can do like this:

```
@Nullable
public static DialogFragment getDialogFragment(@NonNull FragmentManager 
fragmentManager) {
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
    if (fragment instanceof DialogFragment) {
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = (DialogFragment) fragment;
        if (dialogFragment.getShowsDialog()) {
            return dialogFragment;
        }
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        return getDialogFragment(fragment.getChildFragmentManager());
    }

    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    int count = fragments.size();
    if (count > 0) {
        fragment = fragments.get(count -1);

        if (fragment instanceof DialogFragment) {
            DialogFragment dialogFragment = (DialogFragment) fragment;
            if (dialogFragment.getShowsDialog()) {
                return dialogFragment;
            }
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            return getDialogFragment(fragment.getChildFragmentManager());
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

and then

```
public Dialog getDialogFromActivity(Activity activity) {
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = getDialogFragment(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    if (dialogFragment != null) {
        return dialogFragment.getDialog;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs much easier & practical solution:

```
public void onStart() {//or inside other Lifecycle method of DialogFragment
        super.onStart();

        Context ctxt = getContext();

        final AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) getDialog();

        if(ctxt instanceof YourActivity) {
            ((YourActivity) ctxt).saveDialogs = dialog;
        }
    }
```

Inside `YourActivity` create variable `public saveDialogs Dialog;` and  just call Dialog methods on it, such as `if(saveDialogs != null) {saveDialogs.dismiss();}`

Answer (score -1):

If you want get one dialog created in your activity, you can cast your activity.

```
private Dialog getDialogFromActivity(Activity activity){
     Dialog dialog = null;
     NameOfYourClassActivity act = (NameOfYourClassActivity)activity;
     dialog = act.getNameOfyourFieldDialog();
     return dialog;
}
```

Is this what you wanted?